# Is it possible to have multiple Display name pointing on the same Application Site URL?

Tags: facebook, url

We need to localize the Display Name of our application in different lauguages, but we would like to have all names pointing to the same application in order not to split the stats (MAU and others).

Any ideas?

BTW, It's the  same problem encountered by others. Refer to http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10501#c3

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is described in the [Internationalization guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization).  You go to the [translations tool](https://www.facebook.com/translations/admin/dashboard.php) and then select your application.